# Pure virtual function and "cannot allocate an object"

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base abstract class with several methods.

```
base.h

class Base 
{
..
..

virtual void example_1() = 0;
virtual void example_2() = 0;

};

example.h
class Example : public Base
{
virtual void example_1();
virtual void example_2();
};

example.c

void Example :: example_1()
{
cout << "1";
}
void Example :: example_2()
{
cout << "2";
}
```

Pure virtual functions have to be implemented in derived class which I have done so. But I am still not clear why am I getting this error

Error"cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Example'
:example.h 27:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Example':"

main.c:225:25:

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Example'
In file included from main.c:328:0:
example.h:27:7: note: because the following virtual functions are pure within 'Example':
base.h:150:18: note:  virtual void Base::example_1()
base.h:151:18: note:  virtual void Base::example_2()
```

Comment: We need to be able to see MainBase and the actual attempt to initiate an instance too. (perhaps MainBase has pure functions?)

Comment: can you add the code in your main function?

Comment: Show the full error message. Usually the compiler reports the name of the virtual function that was not overrided.

Comment: @JossefHarush which code? example.c?

Comment: @thinkcool: the place where you create your object.

Comment: ok... it's getting clearer. now we just need to see which functions are pure. can you post the full error message?

Comment: Besides the lacking semicolons after class definitions, your code is correct: [ideone](http://ideone.com/mNguEe)

Comment: OK, now you've simplified the code to the point where it works. If you want help you really need to show the part of the code that is actually failing. And showing the part of the error message that you clipped off would help too.

Comment: From my gut: do you have a statement like `new Base` anywhere in your code? Please show us the line of code that your compiler is complaining about, as your class definitions look correct.

Comment: @bstamour: probably not, the compiler complains about example being abstract. but it's just a guessing game until he posts the full error message.

Comment: @thinkcool has your base class some constructors in private section?

Comment: @dsu Hrm, yeah you're right. My poor gut, maybe I should take some medicine.

Comment: @MarkRansom updated error

Comment: My point still stands, and now you've compounded it by not showing the actual errors. It works just fine: http://ideone.com/BDmG9q

Comment: OP, it sounds like there is some pure virtual function in `Base` you _haven't_ overridden in `Example`. Are you sure you spelled everything the same, and haven't left anything out? We're just guessing since you're still not showing a _minimal, complete_ example. And only you know what those line numbers mean in your source files.

Comment: Because the code in this post is correct and since the function names in the error are the same as in this code, there should be no error. My guess is that you're not compiling the code that you think you're compiling. Or you've accidentally fixed typos in your code when posting it here. Also, I accidentally left part of the error message out of the formatting in my edit, sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

After you added the error message i tested your code on an a clean c++ project and your code example works fine.

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Base.h

```
#pragma once
class Base
{

private:
    virtual void example_1() = 0;
    virtual void example_2() = 0;

public:
    Base();
    ~Base();
};
```

Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"


Base::Base()
{
}


Base::~Base()
{
}
```

Example.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Base.h"

class Example : public Base
{
public:

    virtual void example_1();
    virtual void example_2();

    Example();
    ~Example();
};
```

Example.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Example::Example()
{
}


void Example::example_1()
{
    cout << "1";
}
void Example::example_2()
{
    cout << "2";
}

Example::~Example()
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"


int main()
{
    Example ex;

    ex.example_1();

    return 0;

}
```

Try changing the filenames from `*.c` to `*.cpp` 
and checking your problematic code on a clean project

---

You didn't provided full information about your error so i'm guessing that this is the scenario you are dealing with:

```
int main()
{

  // Cannot instantiate, Base is abstract
  Base base1;

  // Should work
  Example example;

  // Should work
  Base* base2 = new Example();

  return 0;

}
```

In your example, `Base` is a class with 2 pure virtual functions -> `Base` is an abstract class.

Therefor  you cannot create an instance of `Base`.

you can create an instance of `Example` or you may have a reference or a pointer to `Base`.